# open source task and time management tool

Tags: open-source

I am looking for a open source tool in any language.

Requirement:
 1. User must be able to enter type i.e bug, task etc, along with the time also.
 2. Once done and finished working on it user should be able to close it.
 3. And one person should be able to generate various report out of this.

Is there any tool which matches this requirement.  Or should i go ahead and start building my own tool. Just wanted to give a try with open source tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what the scope of the requirements are... If you're looking for a very scalable *multi-user* bug, task or issue system [Request Tracker](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) is written in Perl, and rather high-quality... I actually used it for a while to track my own todo list until I concluded it was like hitting a fly with a hammer.

If this is a *personal* todo list, I like Gina Trapani's [todo.sh](http://todotxt.com/), which is essentially a shell script that will track your tasks in a text file...  If you add a priority to the tasks, it colorizes the output in the shell... see her screen cast on the website for more info...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ td ls work
 28: (A) Build a plan for an automation testbed @work p:automation {start: 2011-03-17} {due: 2011-04-17}
 36: (C) Evaluate capirca (python module on google code) as an ACL generation platform @work p:self {start: 2011-03-20} {due: 2011-04-15}
... more stuff...
```

Comment: can i generate various reports using it. like number of open tickets in 1 month or closed ticks in 1 month or closed ticks under 1 user.

Comment: That is definitely Request Tracker

Answer (score 0):

http://www.spiceworks.com/ is another one.